# docker serve content over https without domain (only with public IP Address)

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, openssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two different servers. At Server 1 I have a domain and a IP Address and at Server 2 I have only a public IP Address.
At Server 1 I am hosting a webpage and at Server 2 I am hosting the webservice.
When I want to connect from Server 1 to Server 2 I get the following error:

> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

I dont get it done to serve the content from the webservice over HTTPS. First I tried it with letsencrypt and nginx reverse proxy but there I get the error that an IP Address cant be verified with SSL. Then I tried it without letsencrypt but then I get the content only over http. How can I serve my content with https and docker when I have only a public IP address without a domain?
This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    container_name: proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      ### required for Let's Encrypt certificates
      - nginx_certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - nginx_vhosts:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - nginx_html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    restart: always
  # letsencrypt:
  #   image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
  #   environment:
  #   ### ToDo: Change to your e-mail address
  #     - DEFAULT_EMAIL=XXX@gmail.com
  #     - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=proxy
  #   volumes_from:
  #     - proxy
  #   volumes:
  #     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
  #     - nginx_certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
  #   restart: always
  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=IP_ADDRESS
      - VIRTUAL_PROTO=https
volumes:
  #### NGINX reverse proxy container volumes
  nginx_certs:
  nginx_vhosts:
  nginx_html:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could think of two possible solutions:

#### 1. Add a DNS entry for your domain that points to your backend

If your domain is something like `example.com`, you could use the subdomain `api.example.com` for your backend.

Read more on how to use subdomains here: [How to add subdomain entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322824/how-to-add-subdomain-entry)

#### 2. Add both your servers in a Docker Swarm configuration

If you add both servers to your swarm, you can run the communication over an internal network, which can be encrypted.

You can read more about it in the official Docker Docs: https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/

I can't judge from your question, if this will fit for you, though.

Comment: @zzzzzzzzzzz Not really recommended using a hacky way anyways, but honestly I can't tell you, because I don't know what "When I want to connect from Server 1 to Server 2 I get the following error" is.